# Google sheet Query formula that use text from one column to match another column returning text from adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have a dropdown text column, Claims!B2:B that is supposed to match Ref!A2:A and select Ref!B2:B text.

I tried

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B$2:$B="","", LOOKUP($B$2:$B,Ref!$A$2:$A,Ref!$B$2:$B)))
```

some results not consistent

```
=QUERY(Ref!A2:B,"Select B where A = "&B2:B&"")
```

resulting in error

```
=FILTER(Ref!B2:B,Ref!$A$2:$A=B2:B)
```

wrong results and not arrayed.

I like to know what should be the simplest array formula for the scenario and if possible correct my other trials for my learning process.

Sample data attached. [sample supplier](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EFtRAfks2mAQE6hqjRfPONsYCptudgwPbxaHQ14tUgI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

for your `Category` column

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,Ref!A2:C,3,0)))
```

and for your `GST Stats`

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,Ref!A2:C,2,0)))
```

*(As you notice the only difference is the column number from `2` to `3`)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: Thank you @marikamitsos. 
Will Vlookup still work if my Ref! <Category> is on the left of <Suppliers>?  In this case, what should the formula be?